# Explode a comma in an array value

Tags: codeigniter

> I want to add comma in array return value.

My code is

```
        $to_ids_string = "";           
        $to_id = $this->input->post('to');            
        for ($r = 0; $r < count($this->input->post('to')); $r++) {
            if ($to_ids_string != "") {
                $to_ids_string = $to_ids_string . "," . $to_id[$r];                    
            } else {
                $to_ids_string = $to_id[$r];
            }                  
        }           
            $a = explode(',', $to_ids_string);
            foreach ($a as $item) {
                $user_id = $item;//echo $user_id;   
                $email_id['to_email'] = $this->admin_model-
                >get_email_id($user_id);
                $b = implode(',',$email_id[0]['to_email']);
                echo $b;
            }exit;
```

> when i print  $email_id['to_email'] it will return 
>   Array ( [0] => Array ( [email] => dipti@gmail.com ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [email] => abc@gmail.com ) ) but i want to return email with separated by comma.so i use implode function above but it return error as Message: Array to string conversion

Comment: implode(','array_column($email_id['to_email'],'email'));

Comment: your code is work but out is dipti@gmail.comabc@gmail.com here two mail has not separated by comma ,how to give comma.

Comment: now only i notice that it's inside the foreach . so each time you will get only one mail . so you need to concatinate like this  .declare the variable outside the foreach as empty variable like this $b.='';   then inside foreach concatinate like this $b.=$email_id['to_email'][0]['email'].',';  after foreach you need to remove the additional comma at end of string using rtrim()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now only i notice that it's inside the foreach . so each time you will get only one mail . so you need to concatenate like this .declare the variable outside the foreach as empty variable like this `$b.='';` then inside foreach concatenate like this `$b.=$email_id['to_email'][0]['email'].',';` after foreach you need to remove the additional comma at end of string using `rtrim()`

```
$b='';
foreach ($a as $item) {
         $user_id = $item;//echo $user_id;   
         $email_id['to_email'] = $this->admin_model>get_email_id($user_id);

         $b.=$email_id['to_email'][0]['email'].',';

            }
  echo rtrim($b,',');
```

Comment: glad to help you :)